# Get address of current instruction for x86

Tags: c, linux, assembly, 64-bit, x86

I am using Linux with x86 (64 bit to be precise). Is there a way I can get the address of the current instruction. Actually I want to write my own simplified versions of **setjmp/longjmp**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145173/how-does-longjmp-work), R.. posted a simplified version of **longjmp**. Any idea how **setjmp** is implemented. A simplified version that is, without taking into account of exceptions and signals etc...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe in 64-bit code you can simply do `lea rax, [rip]`.

The 32-bit idiom is:

```
      call next
next: pop eax
```

Comment: And is it possible to do something like that in 32 bit?

Comment: I often require the address repeatedly during a block of code, so I do `call next` and access the value using `[esp]` rather than by popping it into a register. It gives you an extra free register to use and you can just do `add esp, 4` (on a downward growing stack) to clean up the stack when you're done.

Comment: Another option in assembly `mov (r|e)ax, $` or `mylabel: mov (r|e)ax, offset mylabel`.

Comment: this idiom is actually not recommended http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/16/317157.aspx

Comment: `lea rax, [rip]` did not work in NASM 2.10. It seems that RIP can only be used indirectly with `rel` as in `lea rax, [rel _start]`?

Answer (score 11):

If using GCC, you could also use [`__builtin_return_address`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Return-Address.html#Return-Address)

Comment: Keep in mind you'll need to wrap that in a function in order to have the intended effect,  otherwise you'll end up with the return address for the current stack frame rather than the address of the current instruction.

Comment: if using GCC it's easier to use [`somelabel: return &&somelabel;`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)

Comment: @Jason is right and also make sure the definition of the wrapping function containing the __builtin_return_address is not in a header file and will never be inlined.

Comment: @phuclv yes, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777990/is-it-possible-to-store-the-address-of-a-label-in-a-variable-and-use-goto-to-jum

Answer (score 9):

The offset-into-the-current-segment register (`EIP`) is not normally accessible.  However, there is a hackish-way to read it indirectly - you trick the program into pushing the value of EIP onto the stack, then just read it off.  You could create a subroutine that looks like this:

```
GetAddress:
    mov eax, [esp]
    ret
...
    call GetAddress     ; address of this line stored in eax
```

Or, even simpler:

```
    call NextLine
NextLine:
    pop eax             ; address of previous line stored in EAX
```

If you use a `CALL FAR` instruction, the segment value (`CS`) will be pushed on the stack as well.

---

If you're using C, there are various compiler-specific C-extensions you could use on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865862/).  See also [this interesting article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/16/317157.aspx).

Comment: the OP asks about x86_64, which has relative addressing, so there are instructions "accessible" to RIP

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/lib/setjmp.c.html) site gives a simple version of setjmp and longjmp, which is as follows.

```
#include "setjmp.h"

#define OFS_EBP   0
#define OFS_EBX   4
#define OFS_EDI   8
#define OFS_ESI   12
#define OFS_ESP   16
#define OFS_EIP   20

__declspec(naked) int setjmp(jmp_buf env)
{
  __asm
  {
    mov edx, 4[esp]          // Get jmp_buf pointer
    mov eax, [esp]           // Save EIP
    mov OFS_EIP[edx], eax
    mov OFS_EBP[edx], ebp    // Save EBP, EBX, EDI, ESI, and ESP
    mov OFS_EBX[edx], ebx
    mov OFS_EDI[edx], edi
    mov OFS_ESI[edx], esi
    mov OFS_ESP[edx], esp
    xor eax, eax             // Return 0
    ret
  }
}

__declspec(naked) void longjmp(jmp_buf env, int value)
{
  __asm
  {
    mov edx, 4[esp]          // Get jmp_buf pointer
    mov eax, 8[esp]          // Get return value (eax)

    mov esp, OFS_ESP[edx]    // Switch to new stack position
    mov ebx, OFS_EIP[edx]    // Get new EIP value and set as return address
    mov [esp], ebx

    mov ebp, OFS_EBP[edx]    // Restore EBP, EBX, EDI, and ESI
    mov ebx, OFS_EBX[edx]
    mov edi, OFS_EDI[edx]
    mov esi, OFS_ESI[edx]

    ret
  }
}
```

Comment: IS this the answer of your question, @MetallicPriest ?

Comment: Not necessarily, I may tick your answer, if its good :-p!