# Why can't I save the value of rip?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t rip;
int main()
{
    asm(
        "movq %%rip, %0\n" : "=m" (rip)
        );

    sleep(10);
}
```

When I compile I get

```
cc -m64    rip.c   -o rip
/tmp/ccwNbZi1.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccwNbZi1.s:12: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
make: *** [rip] Error 1
```

Comment: You need to hack around it: [Get address of current instruction for x86](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932287/get-address-of-current-instruction-for-x86)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't read `(E|R)IP` because there's no x86(/64) instruction to read it directly.

The only way to "read" it is to make a call with the `CALL` instruction. It will save the return address on the stack and that one you can read.

**UPDATE**: In 64-bit mode you can exploit the `RIP`-relative addressing, so `LEA RAX, [RIP]` will give you the address of itself in `RAX`. Yet another workaround is `MOV RAX, $` in assembly.

Comment: The `mov rax, $` would either be hardcoded by the linker, removing position-independence, or require a relocation at runtime. I would strongly suggest using `lea rax, [rip]` instead.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw There was nothing in the question regarding position-(in)dependence.

Comment: That's why I was only strongly *suggesting* it. Also, position independence is a very common goal in modern programs, mostly for security reasons (ASLR). At least Apple's compilers/assemblers require it for 64-bit programs.

Comment: I don't think `mov rax, $` would make the executable not relocatable for ASLR or any other purposes. The linker and loader should be able to handle it.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Sure, `mov rax,$` is still relocatable, but it's no longer position independent. Just consider an assembly routine, which moves a code block a few bytes: After the move `lea rax,[rip]` will still work, but `mov rax,$` no longer will.

Comment: @drhirsch That will only be a problem if you try to copy/move the already compiled/relocated code manually inside the executing program.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I meant. Assembly is often used for exactly that kind of things. And it is rather "loading a constant which happen to be a pointer to the current address of execution after relocation" than "loading rip".

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can think of to get/set %rip under x86_64 is to use ptrace().
Below is copied from source of ltrace.

```
void* addr = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, (8 * RIP), 0);
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, pid, (8 * RIP), addr);
```

where RIP is a macro defined in /usr/include/sys/reg.h

Comment: RIP-relative `lea` to read it, `jmp` to write it.  This question is about the current thread's RIP, not some other process.