# How to get current instruction in asmjit?

Tags: c++, asmjit

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932287/get-address-of-current-instruction-for-x86), in x64, you can perform `lea rax, [rip]` to get the current instruction. How would I do this using asmjit?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution: `assembler.lea(asmjit::x86::rax, asmjit::x86::ptr(asmjit::x86::rip));`